# Extracting the metadata form Json file making it columns

Tags: python, data-cleaning, dataframe, json

I have the following json data file which I have converted to pandas dataframe. The columns are as follows

```
Index(['id', 'title', 'abstract', 'content', 'metadata'], dtype='object')
```

I am particularly interested in the column 'metadata' an element of the column looks like

```
df_json.loc[78, 'metadata']
"{'classification': {'name': 'Manufacturing, Transport & Logistics'}, 'subClassification': {'name': 'Warehousing, Storage & Distribution'}, 'area': {'name': 'Southern Suburbs & Logan'}, 'location': {'name': 'Brisbane'}, 'suburb': {'name': 'Milton'}, 'workType': {'name': 'Casual/Vacation'}}"
```

So I want to make  columns extracting the information out of 'metadata' columns for example location. I am not sure how to extract it and put it beside the same json file with added columns such as location etc.

```
    id  title   abstract    content metadata    clean_content
0   38915469    Recruitment Consultant  We are looking for someone to focus purely on ...   <HTML><p>Are you looking to join a thriving bu...   {'standout': {'bullet1': 'Join a Sector that i...   Are you looking to join a thriving business th...
1   38934839    Computers Salesperson - Coburg  Passionate about exceptional customer service?...   <HTML><p>&middot;&nbsp;&nbsp;Casual hours as r...   {'additionalSalaryText': 'Attractive Commissio...   middotnbspnbspCasual hours as required transit...
2   38946054    Senior Developer | SA   Readifarians are known for discovering the lat...   <HTML><p>Readify helps organizations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column contains actual dictionaries you can simply use the `.str` accessor to access the data in the dictionary by simply using the keys. For example, if you want to get the location from the dictionary you would use `df_json["metadata"].str["area"].str["name"]` to get the value `'Southern Suburbs & Logan'`.

Comment: I want to collect all the text in each row when I use your command say "df_json['text]= df_json['content] + df_json["metadata"].str["area"].str["name"] "  df_json['text][0] returns nan. Also is it make a dataframe out of the dictionary metadata and put in on the same with title location etc... and put in the same dataframe

Comment: If you run into issues please add some sample data in your OP with the issue you're having. Using the code provided simply returns a `pandas.Series` object with the values, which you can either add as a column to the existing dataframe with the rest of the values or use in a new dataframe.